# Store DataFrame in a dictionary within two for-loops

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

```
ElectricityDemand = []  
FuelDemand = []
dict_of_results = {} 

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep = ';', index_col = False)
# data.csv looks like the following, containing 2 objects: 
# parameter1;parameter2;parameter3
# 388;2000;14
# 293;1890;12.6

list_of_objects = [list(row) for row in data.values]

for item in range(len(list_of_objects)):
   MyObject = Class(parameter1 = list_of_objects[item][0],
                     parameter2 = list_of_objects[item][1],
                     parameter3= list_of_objects[item][2])

   # Load more datafiles and define some constants

   # Iterating over every hour of a year and calculate the ElectricityDemand and FuelDemand of the object
   for h in range(8760):

      # ...calculate here...

      ElectricityDemand.append(MyObject.electricity_demand)
      FuelDemand.append.append(MyObject.fuel_demand)

   results = pd.DataFrame({'ElectricityDemand': ElectricityDemand, 'FuelDemand': FuelDemand})
   for i in range(len(list_of_objects)):
        results['iter'] = i
        dict_of_results[i] = results.copy()
```

This programm iterates over the hours of a year (8760 hours) - see inner loop - for 2 different objects (see outer loop: *range(len(list_of_objects))*).
I'd like to store the results of the inner loop as lists (ElectricityDemand and FuelDemand), then in a (temporary) DataFrame (*results*) and then save the DataFrame in a dictionary, afterwards continuing with the same procedure for object 2.
At this stage, I get a dictionary with 2 DataFrames each having 17520 (8760*2) observations.

I can't find my mistake... How can i manage to get a dictionary with 2 DataFrames (each with 8760 observations)?

**My output now:** 
*dict_of_results*
Type: dict
Size: 2
Value: {0:DataFrame, 1:DataFrame}

*in 0:DataFrame*
Type: DataFrame
Size: (17520, 2)
Value: Column names: ElectricityDemand and FuelDemand
and 17520 rows for ElectricityDemand and FuelDemand (data of object 1 (from input data *388;2000;14*) and object 2 (from input data *293;1890;12.6*)).

*in 1:DataFrame*
Excactly the same as in 0:DataFrame

**My desired output:** *dict_of_results*
Type: dict
Size: 2
Value: {0:DataFrame, 1:DataFrame}

*in 0:DataFrame*
Type: DataFrame
Size: (8760, 2)
Value: Column names: ElectricityDemand and FuelDemand
and 8760 rows for object one (from input data *388;2000;14*)

*in 1:DataFrame*
NOT excactly the same as in 0:DataFrame, but Size: (8760, 2) ElectricityDemand and FuelDemand with the corresponding rows/values/results for the second object (from input data *293;1890;12.6*).

Comment: Where do you initialize the `ElectricityDemand` and `FuelDemand` lists?

Comment: @SergeBallesta In Line 1 and Line 2 i create empty lists for both. With each iteration of the inner loop I increase those lists with the results from the calculations. See *ElectricityDemand.append(MyObject.electricity_demand)* respectively for *FuelDemand*

Comment: @SergeBallesta Could you please help again? See my comment on your answer...

Answer (score 1):

You initialize the `ElectricityDemand` and `FuelDemand` lists before the loop, and then append to them inside the loop. At second pass, they still contain the rows from the first pass.

You should set both variable to a fresh new list inside the loop:

```
...
for item in range(len(list_of_objects)):
    ElectricityDemand = []  
    FuelDemand = []
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry for the (late) pull back, but after all the solution doesn't work! I initialized the Lists as you sad after the _for item in range(len(list_of_objects)):_ but finally I get a Dict with 2 DataFrames each of size (8760, 3) which is good (2+1 variables because of the iteration), but both having the calculation-results of the second object!!